# transfer raid 0 array from freenas to windows

Tags: windows, raid, freebsd, software-raid, truenas

I have three disks in raid 0 with some data on it (not mission critical). This pool was created on a freenas installation and I was wondering if there is a way to re-mount the same raid 0 array in windows server. I created three vdisks in my raid card (one for each drive) and Freenas dealt with the pool creation across the three drives. Is there a way to open the array on windows or at least link the three drives back together in windows. I know the filesystem is going to be a problem but I first want to know if it would be possible at all to re-link these drives in Windows.

Comment: Since FreeNAS is based on FreeBSD and uses ZFS , uhhh , not likely that you can reliably use and recover data from the physical drives when using windows.  But you can obviously destroy any remaining data on them and reformat the drives for use under windows

Comment: About the only way I could think of that would work is maybe if you ran a freebsd VM on Windows and passed those physical drives through to the VM.  Getting Windows to anything useful with it is almost certainly not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a way to re-mount the same raid 0 array in windows server

No, there isn't. Even if it was on a binary level, the FS (FreeNAS uses ZFS) will not be moundable under windows.